# how to check users on login if its already activated

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

users field, activation_key string, status int = 0 default,

activated profile will have status = 1
but it will always login even if the user is not yet activated,

If its already activated then users can login but if not yet activated put a message "please activate first'

assuming my activate method already done,

```
<?php
public function login()
  {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        if (Validation::email($this->request->data['username'])) {
            $this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'email']
                ]
            ]);
            $this->Auth->constructAuthenticate();
            $this->request->data['email'] = $this->request->data['username'];
            unset($this->request->data['username']);
        }
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);

            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check status after authentication and before `setUser()`.

**Example**

```
$user = $this->Auth->identify();

    if($user) {
     if($user['status'] == 0) { 
        $this->Flash->error(__('Your account is not activated yet.please check your email.'),array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
     } else {
       $this->Auth->setUser($user);
        //rest code here
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response :)

Comment: How about using `scope`, What is the standard practice?

Comment: Hello @PradeepSingh , you can edit answer and provide alternate way so it will help for future readers. :)

Comment: @shubham715 Actually you are right, I just checked the cookbook and scope thing is deprecated since 3.1